# AttributeError when trying to use bpy.ops.file.select_file

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using the code below to open the file browser, so that I can select a txt file, where it will get certain values and apply them to the selected group node. I get the error: **Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Renders\Rec Room.blends\BaseModel.blend\Color Parser", line 4, in 
File "D:\Downloads\blender-3.4.0-windows-x64\blender-3.4.0-windows-x64\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in **call**
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.file.select_file" error, could not be found** Why am I getting this error? I used ChatGPT to make this, and have no idea how to do blender scripting, so simple answers would be preferred. Thanks.

````
import bpy

# Open the file browser
bpy.ops.file.select_file(filepath="", filter_blender=False, filter_folder=True, filter_image=False, filter_movie=False, filter_python=False, filter_sound=False, filter_text=True, filter_btx=False, filter_collada=False, filter_alembic=False, filter_font=False, filter_game=False, filter_hdr=False, filter_iplot=False, filter_mdd=False, filter_obj=False, filter_pcd=False, filter_ply=False, filter_svg=False, filter_x3d=False, filter_gpencil=False, filter_affine=False, filemode=9)

# Get the directory path and file name of the selected file
directory_path = bpy.context.space_data.params.directory
file_name = bpy.context.space_data.params.filename

# Construct the full file path
file_path = directory_path + file_name

# Open the file
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
  # Read all lines in the file
  lines = f.readlines()

# Initialize variables to store the values
base_col = None
blue_col = None
green_col = None
red_col = None

# Iterate through all lines in the file
for line in lines:
  # Check if the line starts with "_Base_Col"
  if line.startswith("_Base_Col"):
    # Split the line by "=" and get the second element (the value)
    base_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
  # Check if the line starts with "_Blue_Col"
  elif line.startswith("_Blue_Col"):
    # Split the line by "=" and get the second element (the value)
    blue_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
  # Check if the line starts with "_Green_Col"
  elif line.startswith("_Green_Col"):
    # Split the line by "=" and get the second element (the value)
    green_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
  # Check if the line starts with "_Red_Col"
  elif line.startswith("_Red_Col"):
    # Split the line by "=" and get the second element (the value)
    red_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()

# Get the selected group node
group_node = bpy.context.active_node

# Set the values on the group node
group_node.inputs[0].default_value = (float(red_col), float(green_col), float(blue_col), 1.0)
group_node.inputs[1].default_value = (float(base_col), float(base_col), float(base_col), 1.0)

# Print a message to confirm that the values have been set
print(f"Values set: R = {red_col}, G = {green_col}, B = {blue_col}, BC = {base_col}")
```
````

Comment: I don't know Blender python, but it looks from the docs [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.file.html#bpy.ops.file.select) as if you should just be using "bpy.ops.file.select(...".

Comment: I checked older version blender 2.93, and the method `bpy.ops.file.select_file` does not exist so ChatGPT definitely made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error says:

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Renders\Rec
> Room.blends\BaseModel.blend\Color Parser", line 4, in File
> "D:\Downloads\blender-3.4.0-windows-x64\blender-3.4.0-windows-x64\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py",
> line 113, in call ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
> AttributeError: **Calling operator "bpy.ops.file.select_file" error,
> could not be found**

This means that ChatGPT definitely made a mistake in the generation of the script because there is no such method `select_file` available in Blender python. It looks like the script is supposed to open the File Browser where you can select any Text File (such as `.txt` format) where the text content should have at least 4 lines looking similar to the following format:

```
_Base_Col=53
_Blue_Col=42
_Green_Col=255
_Red_Col=0
```

Here is a modified version of the script that works. It reads the color values from the text file and prints them out and assigns them to the color fields of some nodes which I have temporarily commented out. But you can easily tinker with that part of the code.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper 
from bpy.types import Operator, OperatorFileListElement
from bpy.props import CollectionProperty, StringProperty

class OT_OpenFilebrowser(Operator, ImportHelper): 
    bl_idname = "browse.open_filebrowser" 
    bl_label = "Open the file browser" 
    directory : StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')
    files : CollectionProperty(type=OperatorFileListElement)
    
    def execute(self, context): 

        directory_path = Path(self.directory)   
        file = self.files[0]
        path = directory_path / file.name # Path object

        if not path.exists():
            print("No file")
        
        #lines = path.read_text()
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().split()

        base_col = None
        blue_col = None
        green_col = None
        red_col = None

        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("_Base_Col"):
                base_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
            elif line.startswith("_Blue_Col"):
                blue_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
            elif line.startswith("_Green_Col"):
                green_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()
            elif line.startswith("_Red_Col"):
                red_col = line.split("=")[1].strip()

        #group_node = bpy.context.active_node
        #group_node.inputs[0].default_value = (float(red_col), float(green_col), float(blue_col), 1.0)
        #group_node.inputs[1].default_value = (float(base_col), float(base_col), float(base_col), 1.0)

        print(f"Values set: R = {red_col}, G = {green_col}, B = {blue_col}, BC = {base_col}")

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_class(OT_OpenFilebrowser) 

def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OT_OpenFilebrowser) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.browse.open_filebrowser('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Make sure you open the [`Console Window`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/advanced/command_line/introduction.html) under *Window > Toggle System Console* so you can see the printed output:

[image]

Comment: The exported values I get are always "None" it might be because my values are like this in the file

`[2]
    pair data
     string first = "_Blue_Col"
     ColorRGBA second
      float r = 0.245
      float g = 0.245
      float b = 0.245
      float a = 1`

If you have discord, and could add me that would help a lot more, so I could send the files I'm working with, my discord is Juneee#1732